# Thread id of thread dump not found in application logs

Tags: java, wildfly-9, thread-dump, jstack

Our application is running in wildfly 9.0.1. We had taken thread dump using command **jstack -l** while application was running.
One of thread (default task-201) from thread dump is here

```
"default task-201" #631 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efa502db000 nid=0x3a06a6 runnable [0x00007ef9f7d6b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    - locked <0x00007f0430b2fae8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
    at com.test.common.util.GZIPAwarePostMethod.execute(GZIPAwarePostMethod.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.test.solr.webservice.SearchAppConnector.executeSearch(SearchAppConnector.java:76)
    at com.test.solr.webservice.SearchAppConnector.executeSearch(SearchAppConnector.java:49)
    at com.test.adoddle.search.helper.FileIndexSearchHelper.searchFiles(FileIndexSearchHelper.java:284)
    at com.test.adoddle.service.FilesService.serchFiles(FilesService.java:491)
    at com.test.adoddle.service.FilesService.serchFiles(FilesService.java:451)
    at com.test.adoddle.service.listing.FileListing.getListing(FileListing.java:73)
    at com.test.adoddle.control.common.AdoddleListingController.actionController(AdoddleListingController.java:60)
    at com.test.base.presentation.BaseController.doPost(BaseController.java:408)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at com.test.adoddle.filter.main.CachingFilter.doFilter(CachingFilter.java:66)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.test.adoddle.filter.main.URLRewriteFilter.doFilter(URLRewriteFilter.java:106)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.test.adoddle.filter.main.MainFilter.doFilter(MainFilter.java:156)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at com.test.adoddle.security.filter.SecurityFilter.processRequest(SecurityFilter.java:141)
    at com.test.adoddle.security.filter.SecurityFilter.processFilter(SecurityFilter.java:77)
    at com.test.adoddle.security.filter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:82)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00007efd8a524ce0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

When we find the **default task-201** in application logs, we did not get that. Why are we not finding **default task-201** in application logs?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Why do you expect that it _would_ appear in the application logs? The simplest explanations would be that there isn’t any logging statement in that code path at whatever log level is configured. Another possibility is that the thread is logging, but the logging configuration doesn’t include the thread name. Without knowing anything about the logging behavior or configuration, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @TimMoore
Why do you expect that it would appear in the application logs?
>>We are getting slowness in our application, so we are finding long running thread from multiple thread dump.

Comment: @TimMoore
log level is enabled in our application and also printed thread id. our application logs printed like

'2023-09-05 02:09:17,596 INFO  [com.test.solr.webservice.SearchAppConnector] (default task-92) executeSearch  -> ReqId :[995_22015091957945137] --> Enter '

We are getting some runnable threads of thread dump in application logs, but some runnable threads are not getting.